# Truncate nfloat to two decimal places but never round up

Tags: c#, ios, math, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a `nfloat`. Now I want to have only two decimals, but there should be no rounding involved. If it should be rounded it should be rounded down.

I tried this

```
nfloat test = 45.71629f;
Console.WriteLine (test.ToString("F2"));
```

but here he rounds up (result: 45.72). It should be 45.71. I also tried this extension method

```
// input: 45.71429
public static class MyMathExtension
{
    public static nfloat Truncate(this nfloat value, int digits)
    {
        double mult = Math.Pow(10.0, digits);
        double result = Math.Truncate( mult * value ) / mult;
        return (nfloat) result;
    }
}
```

The output would be 45.71429. I looked into it and it seems the conversion from `double` to `nfloat` fails.

How can I truncate my `nfloat`?

**Edit:**

The same extension method is working fine for `float`! Converting `float` to `nfloat` gives 45.7142906188965. So truncating is not possible?

Comment: `nfloat` can be a `float` or `double` depending on your CPU (32 or 64 bits). However `((float)45.71629f).ToString ("F2")` returns `45.72` to me (32bits)  so it does not seems to be a float/nfloat issue.

Comment: How do I get a `nfloat` with only a limited number of decimals? It can also be something like *45.7100000000*. The `ToString` method introduces a rounding which is not what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have in mind that you can't store exactly `45.71` as an nfloat (nor float nor double), so instead you truncate to as close to `45.71` as the floating point variable allows, and then use the standard formatting functions, which will round to two decimal places and thus show the right result:

```
nfloat a = 45.71629f;
var b = Math.Truncate (a*100);
var c = b / 100;
Console.WriteLine (c.ToString ("F2"));
```

will print

```
45.71
```

Comment: In my code instead of printing it to the console I cast the result to `nfloat`. But as you said it isn`t as exact. For my purpose I'm now using integer values. If you want print it your solution would be a feasible one.

Answer (score 0):

all the standard string formaters and truncate functions do rounding. you'll have to tostring it and cut off the end

```
        double x = 333345.71429f;
        string s = x.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        string y = s;
        if (s.Contains("."))
        {
            y = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(".")) + s.Substring(s.IndexOf("."), Math.Min(3, s.Length - s.IndexOf(".")));
        }
        else
        {
            y = s + ".00";
        }
```

Comment: This is very dangerous. float.ToString() will return the localized format according to OP's locale. E.g. on my computer (Italian) it would return 2,99 (comma instead of period).

Comment: It fails on `333345.71429f`. *Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length*

Comment: I mean obvs its sloppy code with no localization and assuming at least 2 decimal places in the input, but that float tostrings to 333345.7

Answer (score 0):

Almost there with the extension method:

```
float a = 45.71629f;
var b = Math.Truncate(a*100);
Console.Write(b / 100);
```

Comment: The problem is that as I convert from `float` to `nfloat` I get additional decimal places. Otherwise the extension method would work fine.

Comment: It's not an issue of float or nfloat. I wrote float out of habit. This will work regardless because you're not truncating 45.71xxx but 4571.xxx and then dividing again. So you can only have 2 decimal numbers at the end of the procedure.

Comment: I don't know why, but if I print the return value of the extension method on the console it is *45.7099990844727*. In the extension method itself it is correct.

Comment: Don't use the extension method, it's converting from a double. Please use my code.

Comment: Now I tried it without extensions method `nfloat itemWidth = (nfloat)Math.Truncate(45.71629f * 100)/100;
   Console.WriteLine (itemWidth);`, but the system somehow changes it again to *45.7099990844727*. And it's happening in the `nfloat` cast.